# Token not expected processing PDF using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have two very similar pdf files. But if i try to process the first one it throws "Token '373071' was not expected" exception but for other one I can execute the code completely. Below is my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int bufferSize = 20480;
        try
        {

            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            byteBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\Fail.pdf");  
            MemoryStream coverSheetContent = new MemoryStream();

            coverSheetContent.Write(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
            int t = PdfReader.TestPdfFile(coverSheetContent);
            PdfReader.Open(coverSheetContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

I've also added those PDF files. Well, those PDFs are row input for me I do not know where they got created or who does.

[Fail.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eefejz64xtckmi8/Fail.pdf)

[Success.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdw71ipece94u6w/Sucess.pdf)

There are very less information about PDFsharp please do help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SAP tool that was used to create the PDF files adds many filling bytes after the "%%EOF" marker. PDFsharp up to version 1.32 expects the %%EOF marker within the trailing 130 bytes of the file.

You can modify the method `ReadTrailer()` in class `Parser` to search a larger area.

An implementation that searches the complete file can be found here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=583#p583

BTW: You can open the PDF like this:

```
var doc = PdfReader.Open(@"..\..\fail.pdf");
```

No need to allocate a buffer that will never be used, no stream needed.

**Update:** Since 2014 PDFsharp searches the complete PDF file if the "%%EOF" marker cannot be found near the end of the file. So if you are using PDFsharp 1.50 or newer it is no longer necessary to download and modify the code. Those who still use PDFsharp 1.32 or even older versions still have to modify the source.

Comment: How to fix this problem?

Comment: Modify the method ReadTrailer() as shown in the thread on the forum. This requires downloading the source package of PDFsharp.

Comment: I'm still getting this error using PdfSharp 1.50.4740 and there is nothing after the EOF marker.

Comment: @dadde `startxref` should be close to the `%%EOF`. You still get errors with corrupt PDF files. Does that PDF work after using `Save as...` in Adobe Reader?

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow here's my end of pdf file opened in notepad++:
...
endstream
endobj
startxref
477872
%%EOF

also when I look at the file with a HEX viewer there's nothing after the EOF.

Comment: @dadde Comments are a bad place to discuss new questions. I don't have a PDF to investigate this issue. There is nothing after EOF, so it definitely is a different matter and off-topic here.

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow yes I agree, lets leave it for now